# How does pip3 knows it should install packages into the virtual environment, when using symlinks rather than copies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

How does `pip3 install` or `python3 -m  pip install` knows it should install packages into the virtual environment's `lib/python3.8/site-packages` directory?

In particular, `python3` is symlinked as follows:

```
$ ls -la bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 admin  staff    22B Jun 23 14:07 bin/python3@ -> /usr/local/bin/python3
```

I've considered the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable, but unsetting it doesn't seem to change how `pip3` behaves.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 2):

Reading through the code for the shell script `activate` created by venv, I noticed that it doesn't just set the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable. It also sets `PS1` and `PATH`.

It also unsets `PYTHONHOME`. So I would say that combination is what is doing the job.

Have a look at the relevant bits of the script:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/path/to/venv"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

# unset PYTHONHOME if set
# this will fail if PYTHONHOME is set to the empty string (which is bad anyway)
# could use `if (set -u; : $PYTHONHOME) ;` in bash
if [ -n "${PYTHONHOME:-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="${PYTHONHOME:-}"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT:-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="${PS1:-}"
    if [ "x(env) " != x ] ; then
    PS1="(env) ${PS1:-}"
    else
    if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
        # special case for Aspen magic directories
        # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
        PS1="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] $PS1"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1"
    fi
    fi
    export PS1
fi
```

Comment: Thank you. Are you suggestion that, if `python3` is located in `/usr/local/bin/python3.8`, then it will always use `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` for installing packages locally? Thus, if `python3` knows it's located in `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin`, then it will install packages into `$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I think is happening.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `pip` — it's `python` who knows where the directories are:

```
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"
/home/phd/.local

$ ~/.virtualenvs/ansible/bin/python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"
/home/phd/.virtualenvs/ansible
```

Comment: Why does you first command output include `.local`, when your prompt shows you are not in a `.local` directory? Please check my comment to the other answer, and answer it if you can :)

Comment: Because my Pythons live in `/home/phd/.local/{bin,lib}/` and my virtual environments in `/home/phd/.virtualenvs/` (using `virtualenvwrapper`). My prompt doesn't show any directory; `$` means I'm a user, not root; my real prompt is longer and more complex of course. The current directory is completely irrelevant; you don't have to be inside virtualenv root to use it, you don't even need to set `$PATH`, you just need to run the proper `python` (from the `$PATH` or like in my example using full path to the program) or `pip`.

Comment: So, Python always locate the `lib` directory relative to its own position in the file system? I.e if executing `path/to/bin/python`, then it will locate packages in `../lib` (`path/to/lib/python/site-packages`)? And since a virtual environment modifies the `$PATH`, we always call the virtual environment’s Python, including when running `pip`, which is just a Python script with a `#`-line. Can you link to the relevant section in the source code, if you have that level of experience?

Comment: @Shuzheng At pre-compilation configuration you can change `--prefix` or `--exec-prefix`. The knowledge how to get to `lib` is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/80526f68411a9406a9067095fbf6a0f88047cac5/configure#L914). The very name `lib` also could be [changed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/80526f68411a9406a9067095fbf6a0f88047cac5/configure#L1572) but I don't remember I've ever saw it being used. The knowledge about `prefix/lib` is [scattered all over the sources and libraries](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?q=%22prefix%2Flib%22&unscoped_q=%22prefix%2Flib%22).

Comment: `--prefix` and `--exec-prefix` isn't hardcoded at (pre) compilation? They change, e.g. if you copy the `python3` executable into your virtual environment.

Comment: Initial values are hard-coded, not computed: `cd ~/tmp/Python/Python-2.7.18 && ./python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"` -> `/home/phd/.local`. When `python` sees `../lib/pythonX.Y` exists it recalculates prefix: `cd ~/tmp/test/bin && ./python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"` -> `/home/phd/tmp/test`. I've copied `python` to `bin` and `lib/python2.7/*` to `../lib/`. My experiments showed it's not enough to have just `../lib/python2.7/` but I didn't find out what exactly triggered recalculation.